# Open a video in VLC from browser (not plugin)

Tags: firefox, video, vlc-media-player

I'm hoping to find a way in which I can automatically open a video into VLC from a browser (likely Firefox). For example I have a video at http://ip/video.mp4. And I'd like to be able to click on the video an automatically open it in VLC (the full program, not as a plugin). I was hoping for something such as VLC://http://ip/video.mp4 but it doesn't work and am having trouble finding whether this is possible or not.

The last question I found which was similar is a few years old now and didn't have the answer I hoped, so was hoping things would be different now.

Thanks for any help all.

Comment: Try this: http://superuser.com/questions/821352/created-a-custom-protocol-for-vlc-but-vlc-doesnt-like-it

Comment: May be with HTA (HTML APPLICATION) or a batch script !

Comment: If the server set the mime-type properly, so that the browser downloads the file rather than trying to open it directly, then perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with firefox.

Type about:config in the firefox address bar.

Click accept the risk.

Search for mp4

You should see a few preference names that end with mp4.embed.

Please note! This will stop videos working in Facebook.

If these are set to true they will open in firefox. If they are set to false they will open in your default program. just double click the value to change it from true to false. Hope this helps others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This add-on adds a context menu item to send audio/video streams directly to VLC media player:

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/open-in-vlc/

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score -1):

I just accomplished this, but it is not super simple. I created a simple server using `node.js` and the express framework.

Created an endpoint /stream which executes `VLC` with the appropriate URL as a command flag.

Then simply create a start script that can `cd {your server directory here} && node server.js`

Comment: This is an overly complicated solution that is not well described. Either share your code and give better instructions or use a simpler solution.